# How to generate random numbers within a limit in dart

Tags: dart

I need to generate random numbers within a limit.

```
Random random = new Random.secure();
      int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);
```

this will generate the random number within 100. but I want to generate within 50 to 100

how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **generate a random number between 0 and 50** and then **add 50**, to make it between 50 and 100.

```
Random random = new Random.secure();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(51) + 50;
```

Don't forget that the number passed to the method nextInt is excluded, so it will generate a number between 0 and 49 if you pass 50, instead you should pass 51.